# Algebraic definition of the "pseudo complement" of algebraic curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

Not sure if this makes sense.

Let $K$ be field and $C : f(x,y)=0$ algebraic curve curve over $K$.

Define the "pseudo complement" $\hat{C}$ to be the rational surface 
$z f(x,y) - 1=0$ with parametrization $(x,y,z)=(X,Y,1/f(X,Y)$.
($-1$ can be replaced by $-m$ for nonzero $m$).

For $X,Y \in K^2$, $(X,Y,1/f(X,Y)$ is point on $\hat{C}$ iff
$f(X,Y) \ne 0$.

> Are there relations between the invariants of $C$ and $\hat{C}$?

If $K=\mathbb{F}_p$ we have $\#C + \#\hat{C}=p^2$

Comment: This surface should have some connection to Zariski surfaces. Isn't it just an affine version of $ w^m - g~~ = 0$ with  m = def(f) +1 and $g = fz$ ?